# Estoy intentando hacer un Analizador Lexico en Java pero al momento de ejecutar mi JFrame me marca error "AWT-EventQueue-0"

Tags: java, tokens

Este es mi codigo

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class NewMain extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
```

// Definir la lista de tokens válidos

```
private static final String[] TOKENS = {"[a-zA-Z]","[0-9]","=","-","*","/","=","(",")","==","!=","<=","=>","<",">","+=","-=","*=","/=","++","--","||",
      "&&","{","}","[","]",".",";",":",",","true","false","public","private","protected","static","final","abstract","void","int","double","boolean","if","else","while","for","switch","case",
      "break","default","try","catch","finally","this","byte","class","do","char","import","interface","return","new","float","short","implements","extends","native","String", "System.out.println"};

  private JTextArea codeArea;
  private JTable tokenTable;
  private DefaultTableModel tableModel;
public NewMain() {
    super("Diccionario de Tokens");
```

// Crear el área de texto para ingresar el código

```
codeArea = new JTextArea(10, 50);
    JScrollPane codeScrollPane = new JScrollPane(codeArea);
```

// Crear el modelo de tabla y la tabla

```
String[] columnNames = {"ID", "Token", "Tipo/Valor"};
    tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
    tokenTable = new JTable(tableModel);
    JScrollPane tableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(tokenTable);
```

// Crear el botón "Analizar"

```
JButton analyzeButton = new JButton("Analizar");
    analyzeButton.addActionListener(this);
```

// Agregar los componentes a la ventana

```
Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPane.add(codeScrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    contentPane.add(tableScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contentPane.add(analyzeButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

// Configurar la ventana

```
pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
  }



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Analizar")) {
      // Limpiar la tabla
      tableModel.setRowCount(0);

      String code = codeArea.getText();
      String[] lines = code.split("\n");

      // Identificar los tokens en cada línea del código
      int id =  1; // Nueva variable id
```

// arreglado: separar por espacios

```
for (String line : lines) {
        String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
int nextId = 1;

        // Comparar cada token con la lista de tokens válidos
        for (String token : tokens) {
          boolean validToken = false;
          String type = " ";
          int tokenId = -1; // Nueva variable tokenId
for (String valid : TOKENS) {
            if (token.matches(valid)) { // arreglado: usar matches para expresiones regulares
              validToken = true;
              if (valid.equals("[a-zA-Z]") ) {
                type = "Delimitador";
                tokenId = 1; // Asignar el ID 1 
              } else if (valid.equals("[0-9]")) {
                type = "Digitos";
                tokenId = 2;
              } else if (valid.equals("+")) {
                type = "Operadores Aritméticos";
                tokenId = 3;
```

Apartir de aqui puse todos mis tokens con su respectiva ID (69)

// Agregar el token a la tabla

```
if (validToken) {
    tableModel.addRow(new Object[] {tokenId != -1 ? tokenId : id++, token, type}); // Usar el tokenId si está definido
  }
}

      }
    }
  }
```

Y al final el main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         NewMain app = new NewMain();
    }
    
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta imagen muestra mi jframe asi como el error el codigo que esta dentro de caja de texto es para evaluar cada token

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, la imagen no se ve. Intenta copiar y pegar el mensaje de error en esta página.

Comment: El error menciona que un patrón de un regex tiene problemas, verifica en la línea que menciona el error si es que tu patrón esta correctamente escrito.

Answer (score 0):

Esta línea debería estar dando problemas

```
} else if (valid.equals("+")) {
```

Debería ser de esta forma para no causar problemas (el + es carácter reservado)

```
} else if (valid.equals("\\+")) {
```

Comment: Hola Claudio, la siguiente comparación, es válida **valid.equals("+")**, lo que no se puede hacer (arroja un error) es **valid.matches("+")**.

Comment: Gracias mi error

Answer (score 0):

tuve que realizar algunos cambios, para lograr que funcione, primero el error que te arrojaba, si quieres usar **`matches`** para verificar que tienes un "**`*`**", tienes que salvarlo porque dentro del regex, es un carácter reservado osea "**`\\*`**", hay otros como los paréntesis que también dan problemas, te dejo la tarea de buscarlos y corregirlos.
Ahora veamos las correcciones del código:

```
        for( int i = 0; i < TOKENS.length; i++ ) {
            String valid = TOKENS[ i ];    
            if( i == 0 ) {
               type = "Delimitador";
               tokenId = 1;
            }
            else if( i == 1 ) {
               type = "Digitos";
               tokenId = 2;
            }
            else if( i < 30 ) {
               type = "Operadores Aritméticos";
               tokenId = 3;
            }
            else {
               type = "Palabras reservadas";
               tokenId = 4;
            }
            if( token.matches( valid ) ) { // arreglado: usar matches para expresiones regulares      
               validToken = true;
               System.out.println();
               tableModel.addRow( new Object[]{ tokenId, token, type } ); // Usar el tokenId si está definido    
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
tokenTable.setModel( tableModel );
```

Como ves, no son grandes cambios, cambié de tipo de `for`, porque necesito la variable "`i`" para identificar el `Token`, mediante un bloque `if/else if/else` (lo ideal sería que hagas un mapa, al que simplemente le pides el `tipo` e `id`), luego con otro `if` verifico que haya `match` en cuyo caso, agrego una fila al modelo de tabla (creo la tabla asi: tokenTable = new JTable();), y en la última linea, le asigno a la misma el modelo creado (sino mostraba la tabla vacia).